# How to pass url link to the video streaming php file

Tags: php

Instead of providing path of video file to source attribute of video tag, I am using a PHP Script.

There are two php scripts. 1. index.php 2. videoflow.php

In index.php:

```
<video src="videoflow.php" controls></video>
```

In videoflow.php

```
header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
$videoFile=file_open("videos/1.mp4","rb");
while(!feof($videoFile)){
    $data=fread($videoFile,104500);
    echo $data;
    flush();
}
fclose($videoFile);
exit;
```

**What I want is, to pass video url from index.php to videoflow.php.**
I have tried to use, session. But problem with session is, I need to refresh the page twice.

So please guide me, how can I pass a video url from the index.php to videoflow.php ??

Comment: And you can't do `<video src="videoflow.php?vid=1" controls>` and `$video = ($_GET['vid'] ?? null); if ($video=1) {...}` ?

Comment: Hi Robbie. Thanks for your response. The problem with passing parameter in src, instead of streaming video, it provides a mp4 video. In my approach, if I download the video then a blank php script gets downloaded. But if I pass a paremeter then MP4 video gets downloaded. So I have dropped the idea of passing parameter in the src value. But $_GET['vid'] appears helpful. Could you please add more information. Thanks.

Comment: You use `$_GET` to read the parameter you passed in. When passing a paremeter in src, what probably happened is that you had an error in videoflow.php that caused output before the headers, so headers don't get sent/read and this the file downloaded. Give it another crack, but actually check the content of the "download" and you'll probably see content before the header/video. No reason it should be any different otherwise.